# Prevent execution of ruby code in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Is there a way to prevent certain Ruby code from being executed in HAML?

The problem I am having is the following: Users are allowed to
setup their own HAML files in a CMS environment. I want to allow
IF/ELSE and LOOPS within these files, but other ruby code shouldn't
be executed for security reasons.

Do I have to scan the custom HAML files for ruby code and delete
that or is there a better solution?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Greg

Comment: So how you're going to prohibit calling code from if, like `-if File.rm('/')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for some kind of sandbox for templates like [this](https://github.com/svenfuchs/safemode).  I can't speak to the results you might get using this library.  They do say that it is still experimental, but it looks like a good place to start.  If nothing else, you may be able to use their code as a guide for scrubbing your haml.

Comment: As it says on the repository: That code is experimental. If you like to toy with it, fine. But if you want something that is secure for production, it is probably best to use something that is not HAML.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you do, at least not for HAML.

There are other view libraries for Ruby meant to be end-user safe. For example, [Cerubis](https://github.com/daneharrigan/cerubis), or [Liquid](https://github.com/shopify/liquid).

Comment: Or Radius, if you're going that route.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative possibility would be to interpret your HAML client-side using something like [haml.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/haml.js/). In this way there's no chance of contaminating your server via injection or other security holes while still providing access to looping constructs and logic through Javascript.